# Pass an array from controller to model - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Any idea why this won't work? I m getting tags a user has set up and want to get other users' ids that have same tags.

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('tag_model');
            $data['usr_tags'] = $this->tag_model->get_home_tags($user_id);
            $tags = $this->tag_model->get_home_tags($user_id);
            $tag_array = $tags;
            $data['tag_users'] = $this->tag_model->get_tag_users($tag_array);
```

Model:

```
function get_tag_users($tag_array)
    {
            //$tag = array('item1','item2','item3');
            $tag = $tag_array;
            $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("'. implode('","', $tag) .'")';

            $query = $this->db->query($query_str);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach($query->result_array() as $tag_users) {
                            $data[] = $tag_users;
                    }
                    return $data;
            }else{
                    return false;
            }
    }
```

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: models/tag_model.php
Line Number: 20
```

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "lol" } [1]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(4) "here" } [2]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "php" } [3]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(5) "mysql" } }

Comment: $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("'. implode('","', $tag) .'")';

Comment: Try $tag[] = $tag_array;

Comment: Before trying $tag[] = $tag_array; the error showed up 4 times now it only shows up once. Maybe it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$tag_array` looks like this:

```
array(4){
    [0]=> array(1){
        ["tag"]=> string(3) "lol"
    }
    [1]=> array(1){
        ["tag"]=> string(4) "here"
    }
    [2]=> array(1){
        ["tag"]=> string(3) "php"
    }
    [3]=> array(1){
        ["tag"]=> string(5) "mysql"
    }
}
```

It's actually an array of arrays, you can't use `implode` on it.  The "Array to string" conversion happens because each element of the array is an array, which PHP need to convert to a string in order to "implode" them.

You can use `array_map` to get each tag from the array.

```
function get_tag_users($tag_array)
{
    $tag = array_map(function($a){
        return $a['tag'];
    }, $tag_array);
    $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("'. implode('","', $tag) .'")';
```

If you don't have PHP 5.3, you can do it this way:

```
function get_tag_users($tag_array)
{
    $tag = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a["tag"];'), $tag_array);
    $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("'. implode('","', $tag) .'")';
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'` on this line `$tag = array_map(function($a) {`

Comment: @ciprian: Try the 2nd example, it uses `create_function`.  You can pass functions as parameters only in PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 3):

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('tag_model');
$data['usr_tags'] = $this->tag_model->get_home_tags($user_id);
$data['tag_users'] = $this->tag_model->get_tag_users($data['usr_tags']);
```

**Model**

```
function get_tag_users($tag_array)
{
    $tags=array();
    foreach($tag_array as $tag)
    {
        $tags[]= $tag['tag'];
    }
    $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ('.implode(",", $tags).')';
    $query = $this->db->query($query_str);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->results();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note :**  Your `$data['tag_users']` will contain another array of user ids.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE tag IN (Array,Array,Array,Array)

Filename: /home/chatervi/public_html/dev2/models/tag_model.php

Line Number: 21

Comment: Can you post what `$this->tag_model->get_home_tags($user_id);` returns ?

Comment: May be you can try `$data['tag_users'] = $this->tag_model->get_tag_users($data['usr_tags'][0]);` instead, check the controller portion again in the answer.

Comment: this is what a var_dump returns `array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "lol" } [1]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(4) "here" } [2]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "php" } [3]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(5) "mysql" } }` It just returns the tags.

Comment: I think this did it: ($data['usr_tags'][0]) let me run a few tests to see if everything is ok. The errors are not showing up anymore.

Comment: It works, but it only passes the first tag "lol" and I need it pass all of them. How can I pass all of them?

Comment: Nope ... that didn't do it... the way it was before was fine ... it just needed more tags to compare.

Comment: I've updated it again and it was my mistake I placed the code in wrong place.

Comment: `$tags='';` should really be `$tags=array();`

Comment: Thanks but I thought that will add another item inside the array.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: What array?  You're making an array, so you can push elements onto it.